# What is the difference between TIN and SSN when filing a W-9 form?

Tags: taxes, banking

I am a dual French-American citizen living in the US and I need to fill out a W-9 for my French bank account. I'm not sure what to write for the TIN. I looked it up online and found on the IRS website that if I have a SSN, I shouldn't ask for a TIN or write one on the W-9 form. Could anyone explain this to me?
Thanks!

Comment: The official [Form W-9](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjotsn-o6-BAxWnrYkEHbp_AoMQFnoECCMQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.irs.gov%2Fpub%2Firs-pdf%2Ffw9.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2mPwYuKu3uVwy4_2UnGXWl&opi=89978449) gives a choice of entering what are labeled as Social security number or Employer identification number. I notice that the heading of that section is "Taxpayer Identification Number (TIN)". The instructions on the form explain that for individuals the Taxpayer Identification Number is generally the your social security number.

Comment: If you have or are eligible for SSN you aren't eligible for and shouldn't ask for **ITIN**. As per the answer, ITIN is a subset -- and only a subset (i.e. 'proper' in math terminology) -- of TIN.

Answer (score 2):

Taxpayer Identification Number (TIN) is a category that includes Social Security Number (SSN), Individual Taxpayer Identification Number (ITIN) (for individuals who don't have and are not eligible for SSN to file taxes), Employer Identification Number (EIN), Adoption Taxpayer Identification Number, and Preparer Tax Identification Number. Since this is for your bank account, only SSN or ITIN would be applicable, and since you are a US citizen, you are eligible for an SSN and not eligible for an ITIN, so you would provide an SSN.